# BAD_ACCESS exception trying to get the Documents folder URL

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, swift3, nsfilemanager

I have weird issue with core data and iOS9 (9.3). This call throws BAD_ACCESS on iOS9:

```
let documents = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
```

It works nice on iOS 10, but crashes on iOS 9.

I was digging more and found that even if I call this, app crashes:

```
print(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory)
```

What am I missing? Some config somewhere? I tried it on completely new project and on both device/emulator. I temporarily solved it by bridging it from Objective-C, but that is not right solution.

Comment: are you wanting a pre-swift3 solution? or a swift 3 solution that will work on both ios 9 + 10?

Comment: Swift 3 solution for both ios9 + 10

Comment: What does this have to do with core data?

Comment: I use this code to get path for persistent coordinator, but i agree it is not directly related with core data

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let documents = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
```

Comment: I have tested this using the iphone 5 simulator running iOS 9.0

Comment: Hmm that's weird. Looks like some error in my setup. No idea where.

Comment: You could try adding more code to the question and try working backwards

Answer (score 0):

So problem was here:
https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/5055

Waiting for new xcode.